# How to use Swig typemap for a pointer to struct

Tags: python, c, struct, swig, python-extensions

I have a C function:

```
int isInPolygon(Point testPoint, Point* polygon, int n);
```

and the point is a simple struct:

```
typedef struct  {
int x;
int y;} Point;
```

Also Polygon is a list of Points.I defined a typemap in interface for Point:

```
%typemap(in) (Point testPoint){
if (!PyTuple_Check($input)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Expecting a point in a tupple!");
    return NULL;
}}
```

How can I do that for Polygon?

Comment: Iterate over the list and, for each object, ensure it is a point. How do you expect to be done otherwise?

Comment: I found it's usefull to use `%array_class(Point, Polygon);`, but I got a segmentation fault.

Comment: Just for a reference, [Here](https://github.com/ourway/point_in_polygon/blob/master/PointInPolygon.c#L79) is the function i want to use in python.

Comment: @doukremt: Thats my problem. How can I `1.`Iterate | `2.`insure and finally, how can i get rid of that `int n` in the source C function?

Comment: Check the C API. And prepare yourself to write a lot of boilerplate.